# How to Failover from One DBContext to Another

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am working on an open source project that would allow a developer to integrate azure key vault to fetch secrets at run-time and automatically fail-over to a set of backup credentials if the current credentials were stale.

Currently, its working for Azure Service Bus where I can rotate credentials, catch a failure, reissue the same request with the same objects, and then the code goes on it's merry way.

What I noticed with my current attempt of the solution is that you can run `DbContext.Add(entity)` all day but it really doesn't fail until the `DbContext.Save()` method runs. When that happens, a new dbContext would be generated from a context factory but I need to persist all of the changes called from, Add, Update, Delete before the "save Changes" gets called.

Here are the generic methods I use to "retry" on failure, this retry logic works as long as there isn't anything that needs to be passed to the next `DbContext`.

Note: The "Args" passed to the `DbContext` are the username and password to create a new connection string.

_keySet manages the credentials that are "active" vs ones that have gone stale.

```
private G GenericRetry<G>(Func<G> retryMethod)
        {
            G result = default(G);
            try
            {
                result = retryMethod();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException exp)
            {
                _keySet.Rotate();
                string[] args = new string[] { _keySet.Active.Identifier, _keySet.Active.Token };
                _activeContext = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext(args);
                result = GenericRetry(retryMethod);
                _keySet.Refresh();
            }
            return result;
        }

        private G GenericRetry<L,G>(Func<L, G> retryMethod, L parameter)
        {
            G result = default(G);
            try
            {
                result = retryMethod(parameter);
            }
            catch(DbUpdateException exp)
            {
                _keySet.Rotate();
                string[] args = new string[] { _keySet.Active.Identifier, _keySet.Active.Token };
                _activeContext = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext(args);
                result = GenericRetry(retryMethod, parameter);
                _keySet.Refresh();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Any recommendations on how to switch an invalid `DbContext` to a fresh new one and persist all pending changes?

Comment: Failover has no meaning when talking about a DbContext. That's just a session of the ORM that doesn't even use a connection unless you load or save data. `it really doesn't fail until the DbContext.Save() method runs` that's exactly what should happen. There's no connection until `SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like something, probably a "generic repository" *breaks* the way EF normally works. A DbContext collects all changes and sends all of them to the server when `SaveChanges` is called. There's no `Save` and obviously, no need to write something that sends multiple changes yourself. *Retrying* makes sense only if the connection to the server fails. [Connection resiliency and retrying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic) are already built into EF6 and later to handle cloud connection problems

Comment: It's also important to note that some failures just won't be retry-able if your changes are bad.

Comment: `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally, which means any problem will roll back all changes, making retries easier. You can inspect the exceptions thrown to decide whether the operation can be retried or not, eg in case of an optimistic concurrency conflict or deadlock.

Comment: The idea is that I want to use a different user to connect to the database should the current user's credentials have been rotated and the context does not have the latest credentials. I don't want to merely retry with the same connection string, I want to retry with a different connection string and reissue the same requests.

Comment: I'm not looking to have a single connection maintain resiliency but more that if that connection fails for a specific reason (for example, access denied) it will reissue a connection with a different user.